# How to write a range involving negative numbers

Tags: punctuation

How do I write a range involving negative numbers? For example, if you had "Winters in Darwin, NT can range from minus ten to minus thirty degrees", but you wanted to use digits instead, would you write

> Winter is cold in Darwin (-10C - -30C)

Comment: I am not ntive, but I am curious to know what is wrong with " NT can range from -10C to -30C"?

Comment: What _I_ want to know is how you came up with that example? Darwin has never been colder than 12C in recorded history!... http://weather.mla.com.au/climate-history/nt/darwin

Comment: @JohnBurger Well spotted. I use fictional examples in my questions, and The NT News' twitter account [@TheNTNews](https://twitter.com/TheNTNews) sometimes tweets about cold weather, in Darwin or elsewhere.

Comment: You're mixing registers. The conversational "Winter is cold in Darwin" probably wants "Temperatures range from -10C to as low as -30C" rather than a numeric range in parentheses.  If it's formal, follow the guidelines of the house stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I have ever seen a hyphen used to denote a range of negative numbers. Probably the main reason is that it can be confusing.

I have found a number of sources that advise against using a hyphen between negative signs and suggest using *to* instead of a hyphen.

> Winter is cold in Darwin (-10C to -30C)

1. [The APS Online Style Manual](http://www.apsstylemanual.org/oldmanual/mechanics/dashes.htm)
2. [Scribendi](https://www.scribendi.com/advice/using_dashes.en.html)
3. [John Petrie's LifeBlag](http://www.jpetrie.net/grammar/)
4. [physics.illinois.edu](https://physics.illinois.edu/undergrad/SeniorThesis/Numbers.pdf)

If you insist on using symbols, then there might be some formatting trickery you can employ.

> Winter is cold in Darwin (−10C–−30C)
>   `Winter is cold in Darwin (&minus;10C&ndash;&minus;30C)`

You might be able to get away with that, if you believe your audience will not be confused. It is also discussed on our Academia site [here.](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/48699/how-to-format-ranges-including-negative-values-in-tables)

Regarding more formatting trickery, you could try asking the TEX SE site, if you plan to use something like LaTeX.

Comment: (−10C – −30C) - spaces might help.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the sources I saw say that there isn't supposed to space before or after the en dash. But I guess I doubt that anyone would care. And I just realized I should have written en dash not hyphen.